# Sort array and limit to four.

Tags: php

Is there way to sort image by date and then limit to just four recent to show.

```
 <div class="row no-gutter">
        <?php
        $dirname = "assets/img/portfolio/";
        $images = glob($dirname."*.jpg");
        $ignore = Array(".", "..");

        foreach($images as $curimg){
        $name2 =pathinfo($curimg, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        if(!in_array($curimg, $ignore)) {};

        ?>


        <div class="col-sm-3 sm-margin-bottom-30">
            <a href="<?php echo "$curimg"?>" rel="gallery4" class="fancybox img-hover-v2" title="<?php echo "$name2"?>">
                <span><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo "$curimg"?>" alt=""></span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <?php }?>

    </div>
```

Thank you

Comment: *by date* you mean created or last modified, .. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to sort the array by date, then take the 4 most recent:

```
function sortByDate($a, $b)
{
    $aTime = filemtime( $a );
    $bTime = filemtime( $b );

    if ( $aTime === $bTime ) return 0;

    return ( $aTime < $bTime ) ? -1 : 1;
}

$images = glob($dirname."*.jpg");

//Sort with our function
usort( $images, "sortByDate" );

$lastFour = array_slice( $images, -4 );
```

Comment: @UnexpectedPairofColons You could, but as an answer, that might not be as clear to OP. I separated it all out to make it very easy to read, follow and see the different parts.

Comment: @UnexpectedPairofColons why did you delete your comment?